# Front-end validation select tag input field must not be empty rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the following select tag in rails:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => :reports, :action => :monthly_assignments_by_organization_report}, :method => :post, :class=> 'form-horizontal', validate: true) do %>

 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Product Type</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <%= select_tag 'product_id', 
            options_from_collection_for_select(Product.all, :id, :name), :include_blank => "Please select...",
            class: 'form-control single-select', validate: { presence: true, uniqueness: false }
          %>

        </div>
        <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Reporting Month</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <%= text_field_tag "reporting_month", nil,  
            class: "form-control reporting-month", 
            id: "reporting-month", 
            placeholder: "Select Month"
          %>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 pull-right align-right">
           <%= submit_tag "Generate", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I want to perform a fornt-end form validation whereby an error message shows if no option was selected in the input field, meaning a product must be selected.

My code has no model so I can't do a model validation. It has to be javascript or in the view itself.

Any help offered is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Right, and where is the _fornt-end form validation_ code you've already tried?

Comment: thought adding a validate: true in my form will catch it guess i was wrong. right now not sure how to go abt it

Answer (score 0):

have a look into [JQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) maybe it suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming your markup would look like:

```
<select id="product_id" name="product_id">
    <option value="Please select...">Please select...</option>
    <option value="prod1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="prod2">Product 1</option>
    <option value="prod3">Product 1</option>
    <option value="prod4">Product 1</option>
</select>

<input id="commit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Generate" />
```

You could do one of the following.

**Javascript:**

```
var selectElem = document.querySelector("#product_id");
function validateSelect () {
    if (selectElem.selectedIndex === 0) {
        alert ("Please select a product.");
    }
}

selectElem.addEventListener("change", validateSelect);
document.querySelector("#commit").addEventListener("click", validateSelect);
```

**jQuery**

```
var $selectElem = $("#product_id");
function validateSelect() {
    if ($selectElem.prop("selectedIndex") === 0) {
        alert ("Please select a product.");
    }
}

$selectElem.on("change", validateSelect);
$("#commit").on("click", validateSelect);
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ay1g7ndj/)

Comment: im using select2 @LShetty, your answer doesnt quite fit in my problem